# Help understanding the limits of this integration problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find $P(X < 2Y)$ if $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = x + y$ for $X$ and $Y$ each defined over the unit interval.

Now if I understand the problem correctly, that should mean a triangle with the vertices $(0, 0), (\frac{1}{2}, 1), (0, 1)$

To me, drawing it out, it seems like the limits should be $0 - \frac{y}{2}$ and $2x - 1$ which doesn't make any sense for a double integral. So I tried $0 - \frac{y}{2}$ and $0 - 1$ which gave me an answer of $\frac{5}{24}$ whereas the answer is $\frac{19}{24}$ thus I deduce that I'm integrating the wrong side.

Can somebody help me understand how to draw this out properly?

For added assistance, from another problem, $P(Y < 3X)$ I know had the limits (by online help) of $0 - \infty$ and $\frac{y}{3} - y$ but again, I don't understand why. The domain is $0 < x < y$ and $0 < y$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$P(X<2Y) = P(Y>X/2) = \int_0^1 \left[\int_{x/2}^1 (x+y)\, dy \right]\, dx \\=\int_0^1 [1/2 + x - 5x^2/8] \, dx = \frac{19}{24}$$

Comment: $\frac{19}{24}$ in both my book and for WolframAlpha: http://tinyurl.com/m55xgoz

Comment: @David -- yes I corrected. I can add the intermediate steps

Comment: I understand how to do the integral, I don't understand how to find the limits. As in, how did you figure out it was from $\frac{x}{2} - 1$?

Comment: You have $x$ and $y$ both in $[0,1]$ so $y$ is between $x/2$ and $1$ -- as $x$ ranges over $[0,1]$.  The region is the trapezoid with $y=x/2$ as the lower side.  $X < 2Y$ iff $Y>X/2$.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I understand the problem correctly, that should mean a triangle with the vertices $(0,0),(1/2 ,1),(0,1) $

No, it's the area in the unit square *above* the line segment $\overline{(0,0)(1,1/2)}$.  Which is a quadrilateral.

You want $X<2Y, (X,Y)\in[0,1]^2$.

That is: $X\in[0,1), Y\in(X/2,1]$, or $Y\in (0,1], X\in[0,\min(2Y,1))$

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X<2Y)
 & = \int_0^1\int_{x/2}^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y \operatorname d x
\\
 & = \int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{2y} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x \operatorname d y + \int_{1/2}^1\int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y
\end{align}$$

Choose which is easier to integrate.